# Can't declare lambda with auto in VS 14 CTP : conditional expression of type 'void' is illegal

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, lambda

with Visual Studio 2014 CTP, C++ (v140) compiler:

```
auto gp = [&](BYTE* buff) {
     auto gp1 = [](char* bff, char** p1) {
                *p1 = strstr((char*)bff, "(");
                return (*p1);
     };
};
```

Error:

```
conditional expression of type 'void' is illegal
```

(maybe `auto` gets really wrong type there?)

If I declare inner lambda as `std::function<char*(char*, char**)> gp1` then it works

Is there something I do wrong or is it compiler bug?

Comment: An internal compiler error (ICE) is *always* a bug. You are missing a `};` in the first example, but given the error message, I'm guessing that's a copy-pasting error. Sad to say, but this is probably to be expected from an alpha quality compiler.

Comment: The inner lambda takes 2 arguments, so your `std::function` needs to be `std::function<char*(char*, char**)>`. Also, you should be able to use a simple function pointer - `char*(*gp1)(char*, char**) = []...`

Comment: @Praetorian ah,true, it's helped but ... why `auto` doesn't work?

Comment: Who knows ... probably what I said in my first comment. FWIW, if add the missing `};` to your original example the code compiles on VS2013.

Comment: @Praetorian I know that it compiles in `VS2013` :) I will add `};` to make snippet more full

Answer (score 0):

I'm not running 2014, but you may need to specify the inner lambda's return type (which may be defaulting to void), using '-> char*' like this:

```
auto gp = [&](BYTE* buff) {
    auto gp1 = [](char* bff, char** p1) -> char* {
        *p1 = strstr((char*)bff, "(");
        return (*p1);
    };
};
```

Comment: This question is VS2014 specific, is it in standard that I should specify return type like this? why?

Comment: You don't always need to specify a return type.  It depends on whether or not the compiler is capable of deducing the return type.  


I'm not sure why the compiler would be unable to deduce the return type in your case.

FYI, here is the releveant part of the standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf pg 109 (3.4)


Did doing this fix your issue?  It's always possible this isn't what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I fixed issue with declaring it as `std::function` however now I want to know if that is compiler bug or not.

Comment: @Heather I'm not sure, but Clang version 600.0.54 doesn't complain about it at all.  Looking at the standard, I see nothing that implies there's anything wrong with your code.  It could be specifically a VS2014 issue with nested lambdas.  If you just try to compile the inner lambda by itself, does it work?  If so I'd lean in the direction of this being a compiler issue.

Comment: inner lambda works and whole thing works in VC 2013 but not in VC 2015

Comment: Looks like a compiler issue IMO.  You might try reporting this as a potential bug. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzszcehe.aspx